# PHP Time Comparison wrong echo

Tags: php, datetime

```
$first = date("h:iA", strtotime('20:00'));
$second = new DateTime('6:00PM');

if ( $first > $second ) {
  echo 'Correct';
}
else {
  echo 'Wrong';
}
```

That is my current code and is echoing wrong. 8:00PM is greater than 6:00PM right? Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: You're comparing a string with a DateTime.

Comment: `$second` is a DateTime object!

Comment: @Barmar so I need to convert $second to a string?

Comment: you can't compare time by way of strings, either compare both `DateTime` objects or both unix timestamps

Answer (score 4):

Do it with `strtotime` only.

```
$first  = strtotime('20:00');
$second = strtotime('6:00PM');

if ( $first > $second ) {
  echo 'Correct';
}
else {
  echo 'Wrong';
}
```

Hope this will solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Stick with one type USE `strtotime` or `DateTime` class for data/time related operations.

```
$first  = strtotime('20:00');
$second = strtotime('6:00PM');
var_dump($first > $second);
```

OR

```
$first = new DateTime("20:00");
$second = new DateTime("6:00PM");
var_dump($first > $second);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. Like Marmar said before, you are comparing a `String` with a `DateTime` Object.

I just recreated your code and this is a dump result:

```
string '08:00PM' (length=7)

object(DateTime)[1]
  public 'date' => string '2015-04-14 18:00:00' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Paris' (length=12)
```

Comment: i didn't downvote, but you should answer the question fully and how to do it the right way, and by the way its **Barmar**, you misspelled his name.

Comment: You explained the problem well, but you need to answer the question too

Answer (score -1):

I've converted DateTime to String and it works.

```
$first = date("h:iA", strtotime('20:00'));
$date = new DateTime('6:00PM');
$second = $date->format('h:iA');
if ( $first > $second ) {
  echo 'Correct';
}
else {
  echo 'Wrong';
}
```